# Can react-redux act as cache and/or storage for js/css bundles?

Tags: reactjs, uiwebview, react-redux, progressive-web-apps

I built a PWA with react, react-redux, react-router, and react-loadable.  I built an app with Corona which uses a webview to point to the PWA. [The native app gives me access to features the PWA does have on iOS]. That works fine.  However, the webview doesn't support service workers.  As a result nothing gets cached and the app reloads the page every time it is opened.

Is there a way to store the js/css bundles using react-redux?

Perhaps another way to achieve storage (full or partial) to reduce the networking requirements on subsequent opens?

At the moment I am not looking to cache the API calls that happen to a database, but the actual components that are rendered (or the bundles that are loaded to render the components).

I expect this is not a new question, but I've found nothing so far... which leads me to think there is no good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want does not fit with reduxs intentions as a state source. I think localstorage maybe a thing that could help your need.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I guess I can store a component the same as any other variable?  But i'm not sure how to avoid the 'import X from Y' line which always causes a fetch of the bundle.

Comment: How large is your bundle? I think you can try redux-persist as the below comment mentioned. I have used that on mobile and it did really good job to store data to local storage. I think your app will be faster when having data ready to render when it gets open. But it needs your script bundle downloaded anyway.

Comment: Agreed.  I used react-loadable to code split across major regions, the bundles are large at the moment.  One containing AWS-SDK is 300k.  I'm thinking that I could use localStorage inside of the loadable code to do dynamic loading. 
`const LoadableMessages = Loadable({
  loader: () => { 
    if(LOCALSTORAGEHAS('MyMessages') { 
      return LOCALSTORAGE('MyMessages');
    }
    return import('./Messaging/MyMessages');
  },
  loading: Loading,
});
class MessageLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableMessages {...this.props} />;
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Like duc mai pointed out, in a browser/webview environment you can usually use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) API to persist data.

When building with React, I use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to automatically save the redux state with every change. It persists the state as stringified json.